# Bluetooth Hub advice

Tags: bluetooth

I am considering automating the heating in my home via electronic radiator valves with Bluetooth. There will be 19 such valves. I therefore need several bluetooth devices (I am calling them hubs) which will interface to these 19 radiator valves, and allow me to communicate with them from a central PC. The PC will not be within Bluetooth distance of some of the radiators, so I need a device that can be connected to my ethernet LAN, and can then connect to each bluetooth radiator valve within reach and allow me to communicate with it from software on my central PC. I will need several of these devices. Questions:

1. Is what I'm suggesting technically possible?
2. Does a "bluetooth hub" like I'm suggesting exist? Please suggest any candidates that might do the job. Since I have to buy several of these I will be motivated by price to some extent. But also I don't want the hub to get in the way of communication between the radiators and the central host.
3. Any other helpful suggestions.

Thank you - Rowan

Answer (score 0):

If you search the internet for the term "Bluetooth Gateway" you will probably find more solutions nearer to what you are looking for. A cost effective way of doing this would be using a Raspberry Pi Zero W (or WH). I am sure a ESP32 would be another good candidate.

I suspect your radiator values are Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) so that is the way to build the gateway.

Looking into the future, this type of application might be done with [Bluetooth Mesh](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-mesh-networking-an-introduction-for-developers/)